# PHP REGEXP preg_replace Как удалить и последний слеш из угла?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

После обработки регуляркой в `a href` остаются 2 слеша.никак не могу написать так чтобы `url` правильно был сформирован.если заметили там 2 слеша,если с одним то все нормально.в остальных случаях должен оставить одну.

```
$outText = '<p><a href="//trading-conditions/precious-metals/xpd">Palladium</a></p>';
$base_url = 'http://site.com';
$outText = preg_replace("/href\s*=\s*(('(\/[^']*)')|(\"(\/[^\"]*)\"))/ism", 'href="'.$base_url.'$3$5"', $outText);
```

помогите пожалуйста написать правильно.

Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Один из вариантов:

```
<?php
$outText = '<p><a href="//trading-conditions/precious-metals/xpd">Palladium</a></p>';
$base_url = 'http://site.com';
$pattern = '%href\s*=\s*(?P<quote>[\'"])/*(/[^\'"]*)(?P=quote)%i';
$outText = preg_replace($pattern, 'href="'.$base_url.'$2"', $outText);

var_dump($outText);
```

Результат:

```
string(85) "<p><a href="http://site.com/trading-conditions/precious-metals/xpd">Palladium</a></p>"
```

В ссылках не допускаются только символы `"` и `'`, но допускается бесконечное число слэшей вначале (остается только один).

А ваш вариант можно переделать так:

```
$outText = preg_replace("/href\s*=\s*(('\/*(\/[^']*)')|(\"\/*(\/[^\"]*)\"))/is", 'href="'.$base_url.'$3$5"', $outText);
```

Comment: у меня не работает. то есть я html заменил на свой и ни чего

Comment: @Sergey, на какой свой? Я на вашем же примере проверял работу регулярок.

Comment: Извиняюсь ,мой косяк,все работает верно.Спасибо